# Ocultar y mostrar un DIV dependiendo del titulo de la página

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

Les cuento qué es lo que estoy haciendo y por qué pido ayuda. Para ser sincero, soy principiante en Javascript, estoy completando la página web de un amigo y tengo algo que me ha estado dando problemas.

Tenemos un tipo de banner en todas las páginas, en la página de Blog que viene predeterminada en el tema de Wordpress no puedo editar el banner que aparece, entonces se me ocurrió la idea de ocultar el div de esa sección y quedó perfectamente! Ahora deseo colocar el banner que tengo en un código HTML e insertarlo en el header del sitio dedicado al blog.

Entonces, instalé un plugin que inyecta código HTML al header o footer de la página, (El plugin se llama Custom CSS & JS) Pero cuando inyecta el código HTML al header se agrega no solo en la página del blog si no en absolutamente todas las páginas del sitio web. Entonces, no sé si es posible un código Javascript que obtenga el nombre de cada página web cuando se carga, y si el nombre de la página web coincide con el nombre "Blog" se ejecute un código que muestre el header que quiero insertar.

No sé si es mejor insertarlo con PHP (Tampoco sé de ese lenguaje de programación) porque me lo recomendaron agregarlo al php del archivo header del tema. ¿Alguien podría ayudarme a resolver esta duda? Muchas gracias:).

Comment: Tu pregunta es muy amplia y carece de detalles escenciales para poderte ayudar lo cual generaría su cierre, por favor lee [ask]

Comment: Lo estas trabajando de forma local u online? Porque ciertamente creo que se puede editar el código fuente de WordPress. Aunque dejo abierta la duda para los que sepan de este tema

Comment: @BetaM Segun lo que dije, dice que quiere editar el banner que viene por defecto de wordpress pero al no poder instalo un plugin que inyecta html en el header, el problema con esto es que inyecta en todas las paginas, por eso quiere una funcion JS para que adecue al titulo de la pagina y que inyecte ahi nomas

Comment: Hola amigos, muchas gracias por intentar ayudarme. Estoy trabajando la página online, entonces, el código que inserta el plugin se ve en todas las páginas y tengo que pagar para que solo se muestre en una. Entonces, quisiera agregar un código de JS para que dependiendo del titulo de la página se muestre esa fracción de código HTML que escribí para el banner, de esa manera podría tener el mismo banner que el resto de las páginas.

Comment: Entonces estas preguntando como identificar el titulo de la pagina o para su actual url?

Comment: Cualquiera de los dos, lo único que deseo exactamente es que el banner se muestre exclusivamente en la página del blog y se oculte en el resto. Da igual si el proceso obtiene su respuesta de la URL o del título de la página amigo :). @AngeReyna

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo antes de fijarme con el titulo ya que es algo que se puede cambiar fácilmente me fijaría en la url.

```
const pathname = window.location.pathname;
// En caso de que mi url hacia el blog sea esta: http://hola.com/blog-ejemplo.
//Aqui pones la parte final de la url
const pathBlog = '/blog-ejemplo';
if (pathname.includes(pathBlog)){
//Donde "banner" debes poner tu id del banner 
document.getElementById("banner").style.display = 'none';
}
```